# HTML5: Video on the iPad - Custom Zoom Control

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, html

I've created a smaller UIWebView on the iPad, and so I've written my own HTML5 controllers for the video.  Currently when I maximize the video it's showing a pure black screen (Rather than the actual video).  The sound is still working and i can still pause and hit play, however just have a black video. (also when i go back to my minimized mode video isn't there any more).

This of course works fine in the web browser, just not on the iPad.

Here is the maximize code:

```
function fullScreenOn(){
    videoIsFullScreen = true;
    videoOrigWidth = video.offsetWidth;
    videoOrigHeight = video.offsetHeight;
    video.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
    video.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
    video.style.position = "fixed";
    video.style.left = 0;
    video.style.top = 0;
    controls.style.position = "fixed";
    positionController();

    fullScreenControl.className = "fs-active control";
  }

  function fullScreenOff(){
    videoIsFullScreen = false;
    video.style.width = videoOrigWidth + "px";
    video.style.height = videoOrigHeight + "px";
    video.style.position = "static";
    controls.style.position = "absolute";
    positionController();
    fullScreenControl.className = "control";
  }
```

the video variable is my  container.

If it entertains you.. the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of black window]

Cheers

Comment: It looks like it cant find the video... but you can hear sound?

Comment: correct, sound is fine. I can start playing the video in minimized mode; however when I maximize it it doesn't work.  It works fine on browsers, just not in the iPad.  I've also tried doing a .load() on the source once i've maximized it to reload it; however that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on something similar, and I've found that setting position = 'absolute' on the video element causes it to stop displaying video.

Comment: Excellent; thank you. What i did was target a parent element rather than the video and it ended up working great. Good luck!